# SSDT cannot load Package.Dtsx

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have the following environment to develop an SSIS Package : Windows Server 2008 R2, 2 instances of SQL Server 2012 installed (Express and Standard) and SSDT installed. The services of SQL Server Express instance have been stopped.

When I start SSDT to create a new SSIS project I have the following error : "Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document: To design Integration Services packages in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). SSDT has to be installed by one of these editions of SQL Server 2012: Standard. Enterprise. Developer, or Evaluation. To install SSDT, run SQL Server Setup and select SQL Server Data Tools.".

The problem is  that ... SQL Server 2012 Standard is installed on this machine! I've tried to reinstall SSDT but error's still here.

I believe that uninstalling the SQL Express might solve the problem. But :

- Would this solve this problem?
- How can I uninstall a specific instance?

Comment: How are you installing SSDT? How are you attempting to create an SSIS project-VS 2012 or VS 2010?

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall an instance, Go to control panel, uninstall a program.

Go down to 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64)' --Depending on what you have installed.

Click to uninstall it, a small window will open with 3 choices, choose 'Remove'.

A 'Setup Support Rules' window will run and check a few things, click OK.

a New window will appear where you can select the instance you want to remove. Select it and continue uninstalling it.

Comment: I just uninstalled the Express instance. The error message still appears ... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and had to unfortunately resort to uninstalling my Express instance, like the poster said. I uninstalled all of SQL Server 2012- both full and Express instances- and then reinstalled the full instance with all the Data Tools and Reporting Services and the error went away.